# Silverlight indirect references missing from XAP in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, visual-studio-2013, xap

I'm trying to build a Silverlight project created in Visual Studio 2010 with Visual Studio 2013 (this may apply to 2012 as well; we skipped that one).

The build succeeds, but the resulting XAP file is missing assemblies.

Project TARGET contains indirect references to project C:

```
Project TARGET
    References
        Project B

Project B
    References
        Project C
```

When built in 2010, the resulting XAP file contains the DLLs for TARGET, B and C.

When built in 2013, the resulting XAP file contains the DLLs for TARGET and B.

There is no difference in the actual .csproj files, so I don't know how to account for this difference or, more importantly, restore the old behavior.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with images in our silverlight project. After all, we found that visual studio 2013 does not include files with complex names into the XAP. We renamed our "[24x24] Test.png" to "Test.png" and it works fine.